# Why do some android apps start so quickly?

Tags: android, performance, optimization, startup

I've recently taken a look at logcat and noticed that my apps take more time to start than other do. Then I've created a new project with an empty activity, but it is still slower than some other apps.

```
2021-07-20 21:28:17.750 1321-1344/? I/ActivityTaskManager: Displayed com.tutaf.myapplication/.MainActivity: +956ms
```

For comparison:

- Telegram X starts in 400-500 ms
- Firefox: 550-1000 ms
- VLC: 700-900 ms
- 4PDA: 400-600 ms
- Total Commander: 600-800 ms

Why do these apps start faster than an empty app and is there a way to get closer to their result?

Comment: How did you test the empty app? did you create apk? or started the app in IDE?

Comment: Did you clear all the caches before starting your tests?

Comment: @AFarmanbar I tried creating an apk, now app starts in 850-900 ms

Comment: @tutaf we need extra and more detailed information about other apps. logcat of all application and yours.

Comment: @tutaf there are several reasons why they are faster.

Comment: @Eric.1 no, I didn't. Clearing the cache of my empty app didn't significantly affect its startup time. Firefox launched in 1400 ms, the others still start faster than empty app

Comment: @AFarmanbar I cleared cache and force stopped the apps. Then I sequentially launched them: com.tutaf.emptyapp, org.thunderdog.challegram, com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander, ru.fourpda.client. Here is the logcat: https://pastebin.com/zUnUx6YS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigation of the logcat, I have found that during application's `Make-Span`(initiation to display). it suffers from several `Time Consuming Operations`. Moreover, if you mitigate these intense operations, you would be able to speed up the application startup. In the below, I have clarified the problem:

```
2021-07-20 22:43:50.730 => ok
2021-07-20 22:43:50.730 => ok
2021-07-20 22:43:50.748 => ok
2021-07-20 22:43:50.749 => ok
2021-07-20 22:43:50.750 => ok
2021-07-20 22:43:50.792 => spike : 42ms 
2021-07-20 22:43:50.793 => ok
2021-07-20 22:43:50.820 => ok
2021-07-20 22:43:50.822 => ok
2021-07-20 22:43:50.843 => ok
2021-07-20 22:43:50.884 => spike : 41ms
2021-07-20 22:43:50.895 => ok
2021-07-20 22:43:51.170 => spike : 275ms : INTENSE
2021-07-20 22:43:51.171 => ok
2021-07-20 22:43:51.173 => ok
2021-07-20 22:43:51.188 => ok
2021-07-20 22:43:51.189 => ok
2021-07-20 22:43:51.340 => spike : 151ms : INTENSE
2021-07-20 22:43:51.341 => ok
2021-07-20 22:43:51.481 => spike : 140ms : INTENSE
2021-07-20 22:43:51.481 => ok
2021-07-20 22:43:51.494 => ok
2021-07-20 22:43:51.550 => spike : 56ms 
2021-07-20 22:43:51.551 => ok
2021-07-20 22:43:51.676 /.MainActivity: +943ms
```

Accordingly, if you mitigate `INTENSE` spikes (275ms +151ms + 140ms = 566ms), application's startup takes `377ms` (943ms - 566ms), the startup time that you've expected.

**Recommendations**

- Do not make a fat Main Activity
- Do most of operations `async`
- Do not `Data-Intense` operations on Main Activity
- Do not put too many graphical elements in Main Activity's UI
- Make your Main Activity as light-weight as possible

Comment: But this is an app that Android studio automatically generated when I chose "Empty activity" template. So, it is not fat, there are no operations that I can do asynchronously. activity_main.xml contains only a TextViw inside a ConstraintLayout and MainActivity.kt only calls setContentView in onCreate. How can I make it even more ligh-weight?

Comment: The problem was that I built a debug apk, but not a release one. Now app starts in 450-500 ms. Thanks for your answer